# Object becomes transparent/reflective/glowing etc.. in EEVEE Render viewport

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

After new graphics driver update(AMD) eevee render viewport is acting like in the picture. the object gets transparent or reflective or starts glowing and after i click F12 everything get rendered except the objects in the scene. this problem goes away when i switch to cycles
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess we have the same problem. Because I find it hard to rollback the driver, my current solution was to enable High Quality Normals in the Render > Performance section.

My question: [Eevee not rendering properly if High Quality Normals isn't checked](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204984/eevee-not-rendering-properly-if-high-quality-normals-isnt-checked)